# input values into a two dimensional array with java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class schedule with a method createSchedule that is supposed to create a schedule for the whole week. I am using a nested for loop to do the job but I am having an error of this type

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at com.sib.TManager.Schedule.createSchedule(Schedule.java:58)
    at com.sib.TManager.App.main(App.java:32)
```

here is my code and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Can someone help please?

```
  public class Schedule{    
    private String[][] scheduleList;
    private final String[] DAYS={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
    public void createSchedule(){
    Random rdm= new Random();
    ArrayList<String> workstationlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> employeelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner s;
    //load employees into a list
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("EmployeeList.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()){
            employeelist.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //load workstations into a list
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("WorkStationList.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()){
            workstationlist.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //
    System.out.println("List of employees");
    for (Iterator iterator = employeelist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("List of workstations");
    for (Iterator iterator = workstationlist.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
    }
    String[][] mySchedule = new String[DAYS.length][employeelist.size()];
    //creation of the schedule for the week
    for (int i = 0; i < DAYS.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j< employeelist.size(); i++) 
        {
        mySchedule[i][j]="Test";
        }
    }
    //printing schedule in console
for (int i = 0; i < DAYS.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j< employeelist.size(); j++) 
    {
    System.out.println(mySchedule[i][j]);
    }
}
    }
}
public String[][] getScheduleList() {
    return scheduleList;
}
public void setScheduleList(String[][] scheduleList) {
    this.scheduleList = scheduleList;
}


}
```

Comment: where I got this mySchedule[i][j]="Test";

Comment: System.out.println(mySchedule); should read System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(mySchedule[i]));

Comment: You should read [this article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings) and especially [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7125/252965) i.e. I mean shorten your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int j=0; j< employeelist.size(); i++) 
{
   mySchedule[i][j]="Test";
}
```

Are you supposed to increment `i` here?

Comment: You are very detail oriented @Kuma. Thanks for spotting this so quickly.